# How would I access a random item from this list?

Tags: c#

I have created the list below, but now I want to access a random item from it, how would I go about doing it?

```
query = "SELECT id FROM booking WHERE haggle_Remaining>0 AND " +
    "(status='Allocated' OR status='Customer Rejected')";
haggleList = new List<JobComponent.JobList>();
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DbObject.Connection))
{
    if (DbObject.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        DbObject.OpenConnection();
    }
    try
    {
        using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dataReader.Read())
            {
                var item = new JobComponent.JobList
                {
                    JobId = dataReader["id"] + "",
                };
                haggleList.Add(item);
            }
            dataReader.Close();
            DbObject.CloseConnection();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorHandlingComponent.LogError(ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Random Rnd = new Random();
var jobItem = haggleList.ElementAt(Rnd.Next(1, haggleList.Count()));
var selectedJobId = Convert.ToInt32(jobItem.JobId);
```